# R 2.1.3, Windows, problem with double ~ print

Tags: r, windows, printing, terminal, symbols

R versione 2.1.3. Windows OS. Italian keyboard.

Both on Terminal and PowerShell when I try writing a ~ in R with the ascii combination ctrl+126 the result is a double print of the symbol i.e. ~~

This problem doesn't happen on Terminal and PowerShell outside R

This problem doesn't happen on Terminal and PowerShell outside R.

I expect a single print of the ~ symbol

Comment: Can you please confirm that you're really using R version 2.1.3 ? https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/ says that there never was a version 2.1.3 (and version 2.2.0 came out in 2005, 17 years ago ...)

Comment: I'm sorry, a my error the R version is the latest one: 4.1.3

Comment: I note another typo... the keys combination is alt+126. I get the first tilde after the number 6 and the second one when I leave the alt key. I get the same with other combinations, for instance alt+124, alt+121. It seems that the problem is related to the three numbers combination because when I write the combination alt+96 I don't get the same error. Finally note that the bug is not only related to the keyboard input but I get the tilde error also when the input is given by the R extension of vscode